# Do i split the pot?

Tags: home-game

I was playin poker with some friends and I got the hand 8, Q
And my frined had 8, J,
Board was 5 7 6 4 K
Do I win on higher card, or split?

Comment: Thanks for the question. There are lots of examples already on the site that can provide you with a detailed answer. I hope they are useful.

Comment: it is a split, please read the provided links to understand why.